# Sorting subnets by name in Terraform v0.11.14

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to grab a list of subnets by name, filter out the ones which end in "d" (for the "d" Availability Zone), and then grab the IDs of the remaining subnets in Terraform v0.11.14. This is how I create the subnets:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id            = "${var.vpc_id}"
  cidr_block        = "${element(split(",", var.cidrs), count.index)}"
  availability_zone = "${element(split(",", var.azs), count.index)}"
  count             = "${length(split(",", var.cidrs))}"

  tags      { Name = "${var.name}.${element(split(",", var.azs), count.index)}" }
  lifecycle { create_before_destroy = true }
}
```

I know how to achieve my result in Terraform v1.0.0:

```
output "subnet_ids" { value = "${join(",", list(for subnet in aws_subnet.private.*: subnet.id if substr(subnet.name, -1, 1) != "d" ))}" }
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Terraform v0.11.14 by just cutting off the last subnet in hopes that the subnets are by default sorted by name, but they aren't:

```
output "subnet_ids" { value = "${join(",", slice(aws_subnet.private.*.id, 0, length(aws_subnet.private.*.id) - 1))}" }
```

Anyone know how to achieve what I'm trying to do with Terraform v0.11.14?

Comment: What happens if you use same syntax as for TF 1.0. By the way, TF 0.11 is very, very old, and you should start thinking about upgrading, because you will onlyl more and more issues with it as time goes.

Comment: @Marcin unfortunately we're forced to use Terraform v0.11.14 otherwise I'd upgrade and get rid of this problem outright by just using the latest syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the following. As I understand, your filtering is based on the last letter of AZ name. Thus maybe you can sort by AZ, and remove last one, as you tried:

```
locals {
    sorted_az  = "${sort(aws_subnet.private.*.availability_zone)}"
    length_az_minus_1  = "${length(local.sorted_az)-1}"
    azs_without_last = "${slice(local.sorted_az, 0, local.length_az_minus_1)}"   
}

output "subnet_ids" { 
  value = "${ matchkeys(aws_subnet.private.*.id, aws_subnet.private.*.availability_zone, local.azs_without_last)}"
}
```

Comment: This worked! I had to add an extra `join` call to match the formatting but this did the trick! I thought about using matchkeys but I didn't think the order would stay the same from the `aws_subnet.private.*.id` reference and the `aws_subnet.private.*.availability_zone` reference